# Single file select only using File object

Tags: javascript, html

MSDN has an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453204.aspx) of the File object which allows multiple files to be selected

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acquiring File Information</title>  
    <style type="text/css">
      #alert {
        color: red;
        margin: 1em 0;
      }
    </style>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

      function init() {
        checkForFileApiSupport();
        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelection, false);
      }

      function checkForFileApiSupport() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {  
        // All the File APIs are supported.
        } 
        else {  
          document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.";
        }
      }

      function handleFileSelection(evt) {    
        var files = evt.target.files; // The files selected by the user (as a FileList object).

        // "files" is a FileList of file objects. List some file object properties.    
        var output = [];    
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {    
          output.push('<li><strong>', f.name, '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',                  
                      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',                  
                      f.lastModifiedDate, '</li>');    
        }    
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';  
      }  
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /> <!-- The name attribute value is typically paired with the field's data when submitted via a <form> tag. -->
    <output id="list"></output>
    <div id="alert"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to restrict selection to a single file in the Open dialog rather than using `f = files[0]` which may not always be reliable?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you don't want the user to be able to select more than one file, you should remove the `multiple` attribute from the tag.

Change

`<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />`

for

`<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />`

You can check the full list of attributes for the input-type file tag [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/input/file#HTML_Attributes)

Comment: Using the single file select is now not returning `f.size` , `f.type` or `f.lastModifiedDate`. How do I return these similar to selecting multiple files?

Comment: You can get them the same way, by accessing the File object in `evt.target.files[0]`. You can see it working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/5XvFt/)

Comment: Excellent thank you! I hadn't changed `document.getElementById('files')..` to `document.getElementById('file')...`